# How do I move part of a row to a new row in R?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have an issue and I don't know if there's a way out. I have a large spreadsheet (20000 rows and 500 columns) that I need to manipulate, where data was put into additional columns when it should've been put into a 2nd and 3rd row instead.
Each entry spans one large row instead of 3 small rows as it should be. So now I need to create two new rows after each existing row. Then take data in columns C-H through C-L, and move it to the following rows.

```
C-A  C-B  C-C  C-D  C-E  C-F  C-G  C-H  C-I  C-J  C-K  C-L 
A1   A2   A3   A4   A5   A6   A7   A8   A9   A10  A11  A12
B1   B2   B3   B4   B5   B6   B7   B8   B9   B10  B11  B12
```

How do I move observations in C-H through C-L to a new row with some of the existing data so it looks like this:

```
C-A  C-B  C-C  C-D  C-E  C-F  C-G  C-H  C-I  C-J  C-K  C-L 
A1   A2   A3   A4   A5   A6   
A1   A2   A3   A7   A8   A9
A1   A2   A3   A10  A11  A12
B1   B2   B3   B4   B5   B6   
B1   B2   B3   B7   B8   B9
B1   B2   B3   B10  B11  B12
```

And so on, until 20,000 rows becomes 60,000 rows. Is there any help for me out there?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to get data in long format, create a group of 3 values each and get data in wide format again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -(`C-A`:`C-C`)) %>%
  group_by(`C-A`, `C-B`, `C-C`) %>%
  mutate(grp = ceiling(row_number()/3), 
         name = rep(paste0('col', 1:3), length.out = n())) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)

# `C-A` `C-B` `C-C` col1  col2  col3 
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 A1    A2    A3    A4    A5    A6   
#2 A1    A2    A3    A7    A8    A9   
#3 A1    A2    A3    A10   A11   A12  
#4 B1    B2    B3    B4    B5    B6   
#5 B1    B2    B3    B7    B8    B9   
#6 B1    B2    B3    B10   B11   B12
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(`C-A` = c("A1", "B1"), `C-B` = c("A2", "B2"), 
    `C-C` = c("A3", "B3"), `C-D` = c("A4", "B4"), `C-E` = c("A5", 
    "B5"), `C-F` = c("A6", "B6"), `C-G` = c("A7", "B7"), `C-H` = c("A8", 
    "B8"), `C-I` = c("A9", "B9"), `C-J` = c("A10", "B10"), `C-K` = c("A11", 
 "B11"), `C-L` = c("A12", "B12")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```